# Issue related to Background image doesn't show in IE8 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I have following CSS :

```
.rwWindowContent, .rwExternalContent
        {
            border-style: groove !important;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-image: url(background.jpg) !important;
            border-color: GhostWhite;
        }
```

the backgound Image added in above css display well in Mozila,chrome, Safari, and IE9..
but it doesn't display in IE8 only..

as you can see in following Image all the styles related to Background has been removed by IE8 tool:

[image]

Is there any suggestions  ??

Comment: Have you tried:   background-image: url('background.jpg') !important;

Comment: ya it is already there in css class

Comment: Your CSS above doesn't have the apostrophes. Hence my comment. I doubt it works, but it's "proper" to enclose it.

Comment: tried with `repeat / no-repeat` ?

Comment: specify both horizontal and vertical positioning

Comment: Try with a dummy image and see if it helps. If it works you know the error is in the pic, if not, then it's not related to the image. Also check the console in the non-working browsers, maybe they spit something out.

Comment: just in case it's relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/2503231/2256325

Comment: i tried all above answers.. still background image doesn't appear :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure you saved you jpg in RGB mode instead of CMYK. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 needs to know width and height of the container if its empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think better convert your image from `.jpg` to `.png` format.  This may solve your problem.